# Multiple firestore fieldvalue increments on single document billable write count

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

if i have the following:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const batch = admin.firestore().batch();
 const counterRef = admin
    .firestore()
    .collection(COLLECTIONS.counters)
    .doc('daily_counters')
batch.set(counterRef, {
counter_a: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
counter_b: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
counter_c: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
}, { merge: true });
batch.commit();
```

**would the above be counted as 3 writes OR 1 write in terms of billing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One write, because it writes one document.  You don't even need a batch here since it's just one document.  An single set/update will have the same effect.  The main reason to use a batch is to atomically write multiple documents at the same time, or roll back entirely if anything fails.